# Is it possible to run multiple instance of ngrok ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, ngrok

Is it possible to run multiple instances of ngrok ingress controller?

I'm currently running an instance of ngrok ingress controller by following ngrok's [docs](https://ngrok.com/docs/using-ngrok-with/k8s/).

I've installed ngrok ingress controller using this and it works as expected.

```
$ helm install ngrok-ingress-controller-1 ngrok/kubernetes-ingress-controller --namespace pi-deploy 
\ --set credentials.apiKey=$APIKEY1
\ --set credentials.authtoken=$AUTHTOKEN1
\ --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=class1
```

However when I try installing the second ngrok ingress controller with another ngrok account,
it gives me this error

```
$ helm install ngrok-ingress-controller-2 ngrok2/kubernetes-ingress-controller 
\ --namespace sm-website
\ --set credentials.apiKey=APIKEY2
\ --set credentials.authtoken=AUTHTOKEN2
\ --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=class2

Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. 
Unable to continue with install: CustomResourceDefinition "domains.ingress.k8s.ngrok.com" 
in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership 
metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal 
"ngrok-ingress-controller-2": current value is "ngrok-ingress-controller-1"; 
annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal 
"sm-website": current value is "pi-deploy"
```

I've tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69562713/how-to-run-multiple-ingresscontroller-with-same-ingressclass) stackoverflow question but to no avail.

I'm in a pinch here. Any idea how to fix this? or is there any work arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PM from ngrok here. It is not possible to do this today but we have an open issue to track this feature request: https://github.com/ngrok/kubernetes-ingress-controller/issues/87

We'd love for you to add a comment as to your use case to help us prioritize it properly. We are actively working on improving the ingress controller based on community feedback.